# How to get internal transactions when simulate transactions?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, flashbots, mev-boost

My node is built using flashbots' mev-geth, which provides the **eth_callBundle** RPC to simulate a bundle transaction (go-ethereum only provides the **eth_call** RPC, which simulates a single transaction), and this is the result returned by the **eth_callBundle** execution:

```
[
  {
    coinbaseDiff: '500000000207953',
    ethSentToCoinbase: '500000000000000',
    fromAddress: '0xb8393AC9b0d639C67cc9...',
    gasFees: '207953',
    gasPrice: '2404389454',
    gasUsed: 207953,
    toAddress: '0x3c176CcE436705687bBcc8d96FF...',
    txHash: '0x6f120abcc3e4923d6d6d9a435b13317056132...a08bb02500b70',
    value: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000b6'
  },
  {
    coinbaseDiff: '500000000220493',
    ethSentToCoinbase: '500000000000000',
    fromAddress: '0xb8393AC9b0d639C67cc97b...',
    gasFees: '220493',
    gasPrice: '2267645685',
    gasUsed: 220493,
    toAddress: '0x3c176CcE436705687bBc...',
    txHash: '0xb7ac32966f4b902cc415586188334c54...2822bc849b35d9',
    value: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000170edec8cf'
  }
]
```

This result does not contain **internal transactions**,
how to get internal transactions when simulate a transactions?
Thanx lot.